# Which Jenkins Hash Algorithm is used for the HASH8 function in Netezza ? One-at-a-time/lookup2/lookup3/SpookyHash?

Tags: jenkins, netezza

I need to implement the hash8 function, or simulate its input/output in Java. Netezza's brief documentation says that hash8 implements Jenkins Algorithm, but there are multiple algorithms/revisions with [that name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function).

I am wondering which Jenkins algorithm/revision (one-at-a-time/lookup2/lookup3/SpookyHash) does hash8 use? Some of these hash algorithms also require a seed value. How can I get that? Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried with a seed of 0?

Comment: Yes, I have tried SpookyHash with value 0, does not yield the same value as netezza does. My primary concernt though is which Jenkins hashing algorithm revision does netezza use(one-at-a-time/lookup2/lookup3/SpookyHash). How would I get to know that.

Comment: I've tried figuring exactly this out as well... i have no idea.  It's strange because netezza documentation indicates md5 as the "0" algorithm, whereas other documentation indicates it's jenkins.  The result of hash8() returns neither.

Answer (score 0):

The Netezza hash8() function returns a 64 bit integer.

According to release notes over the years, the calculation used in hash8() has changed at least twice since release, so it is not stable between versions of Netezza.