# 'Hash8' equivalence in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, netezza

In Netezza, we have 'Hash8()' which returns the hashed value following jenkins algorithm. For example : **select hash8('Netezza');** would return '**6256861227618928690**' in Netezza.
What would be its Bigquery equivalence? Any leads?

Answer (score 1):

Bigquery has several hash functions, such as `md5()`, `farm_fingerprint()` and "sha" functions.

I would point you to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators) to see which meets your needs.

Comment: I tried the available hash functions but none of them actually seem to solve my purpose. The hash8() function in Netezza returns a 64-bit hash of data. I would like to have the same value returned by BigQuery as that of Netezza. @Gordon

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/r_sqlext_hash8.html

Comment: @BalajeeVenkatesh . . . You are asking too much.  Trying to use hashes across database systems is not a good idea.

Comment: you could implement it using an UDF, but apparently no one has figured out how Netezza implements their HASH8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853336/algorithm-used-for-hash8-function-in-netezza

Comment: This is why we used the open-source FarmHash library for the `FARM_FINGERPRINT` function. It's possible to recreate in other systems outside of BigQuery as opposed to using a proprietary or undocumented algorithm.